# why do we need to pass in window and undefined into this jquery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking at jquery [resize](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-resize/blob/master/jquery.ba-resize.js) plugin and can't understand certain things about how it works:

usually we only pass in Jquery object into jquery plugins, like this:

```
(function($){
    ....plugin code....
})(jQuery);
```

In "resize" plugin there are window and undefined objects being passed in:

```
(function($,window,undefined){
    ....plugin code....
})(jQuery,this);
```

IMHO - window is a global object anyway - why do we need to pass it in? the logic behind passing in undefined object I understand even less. I'm sure there's gotta be some reason for it - but I cannot think of any.

Can someone explain why is it being done?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

this is explained very well in [this](http://paulirish.com/2010/10-things-i-learned-from-the-jquery-source/) video.

basically, you can set those variables in the self invoking function to ensure they work as expected.

"the asshole effect" `undefined = true;` -paul irish

furthermore by passing these as arguments they can also be minified.

ie.

```
(function(A,B,C){
    ....plugin code....
})(jQuery,this);
```

Comment: ha:) dude in the video is funny. great link. thanks