# Passing window and undefined to an immediately invoked anonymous function. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [why do we need to pass in window and undefined into this jquery plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400632/why-do-we-need-to-pass-in-window-and-undefined-into-this-jquery-plugin)

I've seen jQuery source code does this:

```
(function(window, undefined){

...

}(window))
```

I get why is it useful to include undefined, if someone where to change "undefined" before. But window cant be changed. For all I know, it doesnt even need to be used, right? How could this be useful?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/6400632/why-do-we-need-to-pass-in-window-and-undefined-into-this-jquery-plugin](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/6400632/why-do-we-need-to-pass-in-window-and-undefined-into-this-jquery-plugin)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Micro optimisation.

Having `window` as a local variable is marginally faster than a global variable.

It also minifies better. We can now minify the function parameter to `w` and use `w.setTimeout` etc instead of `window.setTimeout`.

Fewer bytes = better

Comment: I dont get the minification thing. You dont even need to write "window.document". You can just write "document", right? And why is window as local variable faster?

Comment: It is faster to access a local variable than a global variable. 'document' alone oblige the intepreter to go look in the global scope. 'window' in `(function (window, undefined) {` is just a **local** parameter name, you could have put `(function (wnd, undefined) {`. It **references** the global object (window) only because you pass it as the parameter when auto-executing the function (at the end - between parenthesis). Don't be fooled by the same name. As 'window' in the function's parameter list is a arbitrary string, you can reduce its length by minifying it and call it for instance 'W'.

Comment: Interesting. It's an issue of performance. So you are saying that, inside the anpnymous function, calling "w.document" is actually faster than writing "document"?

Comment: @Dbugger. It's always faster to access the current scope then going through 'upper' scopes (until global scope if necessary)

Comment: Very interesting stuff. Could you give me an estimate of how much access time is gained?

Comment: @Dbugger. About 30% according to [this](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/efficient-javascript/?page=2#avoidglobal)

Answer (score 9):

Not only what Raynos posted but it also protects your code from people who do something like this in other libraries that may be on your page or gain access to the page in some other way:

```
undefined = true;
```

In other words, it protects you from other people doing stupid things like redefining common global variables or objects.

Comment: Yeah, i already said in my post that I get why undefined must be included.

Comment: NP, left here for someone else who may not know.