# What is this javascript notation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found it [here](http://codepen.io/mjau-mjau/pen/yDKBh)

```
;(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
//code
}(jQuery, this, this.document));
```

This is the first time I see something like this. What it is and how it is interpreted? I don't understand why does it have to pass this and this.document, and what's with the 'undefined'.

The reason I am asking is because I included it in my page and

```
  if($('ul.mtree').length)
```

Returns false, despite it returning true when I type it in the console.

Comment: @ZachLeighton, the question is kind of confusing, but I think George is asking about the jquery document load

Comment: I don't understand why does it have to pass this and this.document, and what's with the 'undefined'

Comment: @NathanKoop good catch, I looked quickly and saw the semi-colon figured it was that.

Comment: related [why do we need to pass in window and undefined into this jquery plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400632/why-do-we-need-to-pass-in-window-and-undefined-into-this-jquery-plugin)

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc please update the question with this information

Comment: Just to be clear, this is not a special notation. It's just a function call.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The first semi-colon `;` sets the following code apart from any other preceding code that may have forgot the semi-colon. This is important as the parens will try to run the previous statements as a function if the semi colon was not found.

For the rest of the code, we are just declaring an "in-line" function which will be immediately executed where the arguments `$, window, document` are then instantiated as `jQuery, this, this.document` (respectively) from the global scope. This is primarily so that you can use "$" within your new jQuery plugin without worrying if `$` has been overwritten somewhere else. You can be sure that `$` is the same as `jQuery`.

Read more about "Protecting the $ Alias and Adding Scope" [here](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/#protecting-the-alias-and-adding-scope)

**Update from OP**:

For the `if` statement returning false, be sure that your html is loaded at the time of calling your `if` statement. One quick way to do this, is to wrap it in a `$(document).ready` method like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if($('ul.mtree').length) {
         alert("got 'em!");
    }
});
```

Comment: Just to mention : it helps a lot with minifications of js code.

Comment: Yes! Good point @RoyiNamir

Comment: Also : you forgot to mention that undefined could be overriden by a user code ( I dont think it's the case now days) but it is safest to send nothing to a variable so you can be certain that it has `undefined` value

Comment: Nice about the `undefined`, I missed that.

Comment: The document ready didn't solve it, it was because that example was using an old version of velocity. And the curent version doesn't include that function(for everyone that might want to run that example).

Answer (score 3):

It's an immediately executed function.  The ; at the start protects from potential syntax errors after minification.

The function itself provides for scoping of the arguments rather than referencing them at global scope.  It also provides for privacy of local variables defined with the function.  The somewhat confusing final parameter passed of `undefined` protects against malicious changes to what undefined represents at the global scope.

Lots of resources available if you google for javascript terms such as self executing functions, global scope, closures, module pattern.

Comment: Good call about the `undefined`. I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

It might be helpful to include a copy of the code you have which is not working.

But to answer the question about why `if($('ul.mtree').length)` can return `true` at console, but `false` in the page could depend on timing (e.g. the function executes before the DOM has loaded). By the time you load up the console to check the value, the DOM is loaded and it returns true.

Make sure to include your JS at the end of the page, or only call after document load.

Comment: It might be helpful to include the "document load" syntax for the OP

Comment: Good call, I initially left it out since I didn't want to make any assumptions about OP's code.I would edit it in, but looks like you already edited your answer to include a sample so I'll leave mine alone to limit duplication.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, that code is supposed to fix the case in which `$`, `window` or `document` have been shadowed with other values:

```
(function() {
var window = 123,
    document = 'abc',
    $ = Function.prototype;
})();
```

Then,

- `$` is a shorthand used by `jQuery` and other libraries. The code assumes `jQuery` hasn't been shadowed with something other, so it creates a variable named `$` with the value of `jQuery`.
- `this` is a keyword. When not explicitly set in non-strict mode, it becomes the global object. So your code creates a local variable `window` with that value. Note this is dangerous, because `this` could have been set to some value, or be `undefined` in strict mode.
- Assuming `this` is the global object, `this.document` will be the document object.
- `undefined` was a property of the global object which didn't have the ReadOnly attribute in ECMAScript 3, so it could be overwritten. Your code creates a local variable without assigning any value, so it becomes the real undefined. This is no longer needed since ECMAScript 5, because `window.undefined` has the [[Configurable]] and [[Writable]] attributes set to `false`.

Then,

```
(function() {
var window = 123,
    document = 'abc',
    $ = Function.prototype;
    (function($, window, document, undefined) {
        // `$`, `window`, `document` and `undefined` have been restored
    })(jQuery, this, this.document);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question correctly,the function of notation `;` ahead of the function statement,such as

```
(function(){
    console.log('no name');
})();

(function(){
    console.log('no name')
}());

-function(){
    console.log('no name');
}();

+function(){
    console.log('no name');
}();

~function(){
    console.log('no name');
}();

!function(){
    console.log('no name');
}();
```

you'll see the notation ,such as '()','-','+','~','!'

and the function of the notation is that parse the function statement into expression and execute the function immediately!

but i suggest you just use '()' to execute the function statement,because it is the formal way and regular way to use in routine.